# Avoiding extraneous solutions in deriving parabola equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry

**My question is on deriving the parabola equation given a directrix and a focus. I think below is a valid equation for a parabola? So, how do you avoid extraneous solutions here:**
$$\sqrt{(x - f_x)^2 + (y - f_y)^2} = \sqrt{(y + f_y)^2} $$

It seems in the sources that I've seen that the next step to simplifying this equation is to square both sides and create the following like equation:
$$ (x - f_x)^2 + (y - f_y)^2 = (y + f_y)^2 $$
Is this a valid step? It seems so, but why aren't there extraneous solutions? I get that solutions to the original equation are solutions to the second derived equation but I don't get why there wouldn't be extra solutions for the second equation that are not solutions to the first equation?

Comment: Under the square roots you have expressions which cannot be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squaring both sides of an equation can, but doesn't necessarily, introduce extraneous solutions. In particular, they can happen if the two sides can have different signs.

It's true that

$$ L = R \implies L^2 = R^2 $$

but not true that

$$ L^2 = R^2 \implies L = R $$

since we also have the possibility that $L = -R \neq 0$ and $L^2 = R^2$. Solutions to $L = -R \neq 0$, if any, are the extraneous solutions to $L^2 = R^2$ which are not solutions to the original $L=R$.

In this case, since the square root of a real number is never negative, it's not possible that

$$ \sqrt{(x-f_x)^2+(y-f_y)^2} = -\sqrt{(y+f(y))^2} \neq 0 $$

So this time, no extraneous solutions exist.

Comment: Ok, Thank you!!